# Docker: filesystem changes not exporting

Tags: docker, boot2docker

TL;DR My `docker save/export` isn't working and I don't know why.

I'm using boot2docker for Mac.

I've created a Wordpress installation proof of concept, and am using BusyBox as both the MySQL container as well as the main file system container.  I created these containers using:

```
> docker run -v /var/lib/mysql --name=wp_datastore -d busybox
> docker run -v /var/www/html --name=http_root -d busybox
```

Running `docker ps -a` shows two containers, both based on `busybox:latest`.  SO far so good.  Then I create the Wordpress and MySQL containers, pointing to their respective data containers:

```
>docker run \
--name mysql_db \
-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=somepassword \
--volumes-from wp_datastore \
-d mysql

>docker run \
--name=wp_site \
--link=mysql_db:mysql \
-p 80:80 \
--volumes-from http_root \
-d wordpress
```

I go to my url (`boot2docker ip`) and there's a brand new Wordpress application.  I go ahead and set up the Wordpress site by adding a theme and some images.  I then `docker inspect http_root` and sure enough the filesystem changes are all there.

I then commit the changed containers:

```
>docker commit http_root evilnode/http_root:dev
>docker commit wp_datastore evilnode/wp_datastore:dev
```

I verify that my new images are there.  Then I save the images:

```
> docker save -o ~/tmp/http_root.tar evilnode/http_root:dev
> docker save -o ~/tmp/wp_datastore.tar evilnode/wp_datastore:dev
```

I verify that the tar files are there as well.  So far, so good.

Here is where I get a bit confused.  I'm not entirely sure if I need to, but I also export the containers:

```
> docker export http_root > ~/tmp/http_root_snapshot.tar
> docker export wp_datastore > ~/tmp/wp_datastore_snapshot.tar
```

So I now have 4 tar files:

- http_root.tar (saved image)
- wp_datastore.tar (saved image)
- http_root_snapshot.tar (exported container)
- wp_datastore_snapshot.tar (exported container)

I SCP these tar files to another machine, then proceed to build as follows:

```
>docker load -i ~/tmp/wp_datastore.tar
>docker load -i ~/tmp/http_root.tar
```

The images `evilnode/wp_datastore:dev` and `evilnode/http_root:dev` are loaded.

```
>docker run -v /var/lib/mysql --name=wp_datastore -d evilnode/wp_datastore:dev
>docker run -v /var/www/html --name=http_root -d evilnode/http_root:dev
```

**If I understand correctly, containers were just created based on my images**.

Sure enough, the containers are there.  However, if I `docker inspect http_root`, and go to the file location aliased by `/var/www/html`, the directory is completely empty.  *OK...*

So then I think I need to import into the new containers since images don't contain file system changes.  I do this:

```
>cat http_root.snapshot.tar | docker import - http_root
```

**I understand this to mean that I am importing a file system delta from one container into another**.  However, when I go back to the location aliased by `/var/www/html`, I see the same empty directory.

How do I export the changes from these containers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Volumes are not exported with the new image. The proper way to manage data in Docker is to use a data container and use a command like `docker run --volumes-from dbdata -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /dbdata` or `docker cp` to backup data and transfer it around. https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes

Comment: Behind the scenes, container volumes are bind mounts to directories on the host (or in the case of boot2docker, the VM). Hence they're not included in the Copy-on-Write filesystem used by Docker, and so they're not part of the image layers. Therefore they don't get included in an `export` or `save`.